How to get list of all endpoints in FastEndpoints?
In our app we need to get list of all FastEndpoints endpoints at runtime.
Basically we need the following info for all endpoints;
GroupName (null if not belongs to any group)
EndpointName (Name of endpoint class)
Route (including any route prefixes if applied)
HttpMethod
Previously we were obtaining same kind of information for ApiControllers by enumerating ControllerActionDescriptor type of IActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.
FastEndpoints has EndPointData class for internally scanning endpoints when UseFastEndpoints is called, but this class is internal and can not be used outside.

The question is unclear. What does at runtime mean? Don't you know what your project does? Even if your project is a gateway that loads other libraries, you do know what those libraries are at compile time. In both cases you can generate a Swagger JSON doc that describes all endpoints. Unless you're loading DLLs from disk at runtime.

@PanagiotisKanavos utilization of swagger for this purposes is out of question unfortunately. Just need to enumerate available endpoints and get the relevant data of the current assembly. Hope this clarifies.

out of the question doesn't explain what you want. If you want help, explain the actual problem. FastEndpoints is still an ASP.NET Core library and MapFastEndpoints actually registers routes using ASP.NET Core's methods. So the problem may be how to list the registered ASP.NET Core endpoints and methods

Check How to list all routes in an ASP.NET Core application. As Gerald Barre explains, all flavors of ASP.NET Core use the same routings system, which stores route info in EndpointDataSource objects and registers them in the DI container. You can request all of them as IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource>

@PanagiotisKanavos thank you for your time and answer, this route is suitable for what we are trying to achieve. Btw, If you post this as an answer I'd like to mark it as accepted one.

FastEndpoints is built on top of ASP.NET Core and uses the same routing middleware. Looking at the MapEndpoints source we see it uses the same methods as Minimal APIs to register endpoints and actions :
foreach (var verb in def.Verbs)
{
    var hb = app.MapMethods(
        finalRoute,
        [verb],
        (HttpContext ctx, [FromServices] IEndpointFactory factory) => RequestHandler.Invoke(ctx, factory));

    hb.WithName(..._;
    ....
    hb.WithMetadata(def);
    ...

This means the actual problem becomes finding all the routes in an ASP.NET Core applications. Gérald Barré's How to list all routes in an ASP.NET Core application article shows how to do that for all flavors of ASP.NET Core (Minimal API, Controllers, Razor Pages, gRPC etc). All endpoints are registered as EndpointDataSource objects. To retrieve all of them, we can request IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> :
...
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.MapGet("/debug/routes", (IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> endpointSources) =>
        string.Join("\n", endpointSources.SelectMany(source => source.Endpoints)));
}

app.Run();

That interface allows retrieving more than just the route as the next example shows :
app.MapGet("/debug/routes", (IEnumerable<EndpointDataSource> endpointSources) =>
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var endpoints = endpointSources.SelectMany(es => es.Endpoints);
    foreach (var endpoint in endpoints)
    {
        if(endpoint is RouteEndpoint routeEndpoint)
        {
            _ = routeEndpoint.RoutePattern.RawText;
            _ = routeEndpoint.RoutePattern.PathSegments;
            _ = routeEndpoint.RoutePattern.Parameters;
            _ = routeEndpoint.RoutePattern.InboundPrecedence;
            _ = routeEndpoint.RoutePattern.OutboundPrecedence;
        }

        var routeNameMetadata = endpoint.Metadata.OfType<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteNameMetadata>().FirstOrDefault();
        _ = routeNameMetadata?.RouteName;

        var httpMethodsMetadata = endpoint.Metadata.OfType<HttpMethodMetadata>().FirstOrDefault();
        _ = httpMethodsMetadata?.HttpMethods; // [GET, POST, ...]

        // There are many more metadata types available...
});

This is actually mentioned in the Endpoint Definition section of the Routing docs which ... I've never bothered to read before :

An ASP.NET Core endpoint is:

Executable: Has a RequestDelegate.
Extensible: Has a Metadata collection.
Selectable: Optionally, has routing information.
Enumerable: The collection of endpoints can be listed by retrieving the EndpointDataSource from DI.



Swagger is the tool for you - it takes care of schema generation for your API. It generates convenient UI as well as possibility to generate JSON file with info about your API (models, URLs, and you can also customize it to contain more information).
Swagger integrates nicely with FastEndpoints, sample app:

create app and install necessary packages:
dotnet new web
dotnet add package FastEndpoints
dotnet add package Swashbuckle.AspNetCore


add this code to program startup with sample classes for Endpoint:
using FastEndpoints;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
builder.Services.AddFastEndpoints();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseFastEndpoints();
app.Run();

public class MyRequest
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class MyResponse
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public bool IsOver18 { get; set; }
}

public class MyEndpoint : Endpoint<MyRequest, MyResponse>
{
    public override void Configure()
    {
        Post("/api/user/create");
        AllowAnonymous();
    }

    public override async Task HandleAsync(MyRequest req, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        await SendAsync(new()
        {
            FullName = req.FirstName + " " + req.LastName,
            IsOver18 = req.Age > 18
        });
    }
}



UPDATE
Swagger is doing all the hardwork already, if you want to get all endpoints, you can hook up into Swagger mechanism through IOperationFilter
public class OperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    static List<OpenApiOperation> _allEndpoints = new();

    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        _allEndpoints.Add(operation);
    }
}

You just need to register it with:
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.AddOperationFilterInstance(new OperationFilter());
});

Of course, you would need to adjust where you persist this info and how you can use it in other classes during runtime.
Reference: ASP.NET Core web API documentation with Swagger / OpenAPI

Hi, no swagger is not the concern of this question unfortunately, we need to obtain endpoint list and their relevant data at runtime.

@OnurBuyukcaglar See my update

thank you for clarification, but unfortunately we opted out of swagger generation since the project has tons of microservices that are http api enabled. We need to obtain this information without resorting to swagger. Thanks.

@OnurBuyukcaglar that's exactly what Swagger is for. The question contradicts itself - you want what Swagger does without using Swagger. So you actually want to reinvent Swagger all by yourself

@PanagiotisKanavos The point is we neither need the documentation nor the UI testing provided by swagger hence the build overhead. We only need to aware of the available endpoints.

@OnurBuyukcaglar Then there is another option (I went that route once forcibly in other subject..) - go to swagger Git repo, analyze what they do and how they do, extract minimal needed logic to achieve your goal, done.
